# How to use LG Magic Remote to control a Mac when using AirPlay

Tags: airplay, remote-control

I have recently bought an LG tv running webOS 5 and figured out that I can easily mirror the screen of my 27" iMac running macOS Mojave. The problem is that I have to take my MagicMouse into the living room where I already have MagicRemote which acts like an air mouse. I've couldn't find any options that would enable controlling iMac from tv.
According to this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QldjEJLslDE&ab_channel=IP69
it seems to be possible to control a Windows PC with a LG Magic Remote when mirroring screen on webOS tv.
Is there any way to do it on an iMac as well?